# Что произойдет при несоответствии сигнатур функций по константности аргументов при экспорте/загрузке из DLL?

Tags: c++, c, dll, const

Рассмотрим два следующих прототипа функций:

```
extern "C"
{
    void a(void* p);
    void b(const void* p);
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, влияет ли спецификатор константности аргумента функции на генерируемый код при экспорте символа из `DLL`?

Конкретно меня интересует следующая ситуация:

Внутри `DLL` функция экспортируется как:

```
extern "C" void func(const void* p);
```

Но пользователь библиотеки работает с загруженной функцией через указатель, который имеет сигнатуру:

```
void (*)(void*);
```

Я понимаю, что если сделать наоборот, то будет плохо. Но если сделать так?

Comment: Ну формально плохо будет в любом случае, но на практике это вряд ли чем-то грозит